# Docs generated by sphinx: make a search in source code as well

Tags: python-3.x, documentation, python-sphinx

When I search for certain keywords on sphinx generated documentation from a python package (generated with a `conf.py` and the `sphinx-apidoc`), this search yields results of the documentation produced based on the docstrings only. However, my documentation also includes the source code, which is saved locally in the `_modules` folder. Is there a simple configuration or possibility to make the search run on the source code as well? After checking the [sphinx configuration documentation](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html) I could not find a solution for this. Also in other posts, only slightly related to this question, there was mention to use another search software like Algolia, but my documentation is private.

I am currently using `sphinx 3.5.3` and am building the docs both on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Hello, which version of Sphinx are you using?

Comment: Added info in the edit.

Comment: No, there is't any simple configuration to make the search run on the source code. I suggest that you submit a feature request: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/new/choose